# .theanorc file in MacOS does not apply

Tags: theano

I've been getting this error working with Theano:

*AssertionError: AbstractConv2d Theano optimization failed: there is no implementation available supporting the requested options. Did you exclude both "conv_dnn" and "conv_gemm" from the optimizer? If on GPU, is cuDNN available and does the GPU support it? If on CPU, do you have a BLAS library installed Theano can link against?*

So I changed the .theanorc file at my home-directory to:

```
[global]
optimizer = None
```

And tested whether it applies with:

```
print(theano.config)
```

Strangely it still says:

```
optimizer (('fast_run', 'merge', 'fast_compile', 'None')) 
    Doc:  Default optimizer. If not None, will use this optimizer with the Mode
    Value:  fast_run
```

Does anyone has a similar issue on MacOS? And knows how to fix it?

FIXED: Just needed to restart the jupyter notebook kernel and do a `theano-cache clear` after that the .theanorc file applies

Comment: I have had this issue on Ubuntu. Do you have `1x1` convolutions in your network and how deep is your network? However, I had a GPU and BLAS. So do you have GPU and/or BLAS?

Comment: @Parag I've been trying to run the code from: [link] (https://github.com/mikesj-public/convolutional_autoencoder/blob/master/mnist_conv_autoencode.ipynb) it appears to have 15 layers. Although I'm unsure since I still learn. The error is not thrown at training, it is thrown at cell 16. Training has been done on CPU and I have tried mnually reinstalling my gcc compiler and BLAS aswell.

Comment: Since your .theanorc file does not have any effect, you can try running using this command. This takes precedence over .theanorc file. `THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32,device=cpu'  python <myscript>.py`. See [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) for more information.

Comment: @Parag the most simple thing helped... I just needed to restart my jupyter notebook kernel... -*facepalm*-... thanks for your reply anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: Just needed to restart the jupyter notebook kernel and do a `theano-cache clear` after that the .theanorc file applies